# jQuery preventDefault (and return false) not working in Safari after geoLocation refused

Tags: jquery, safari, geolocation, preventdefault

I have some geoLocation code which works in every situation but one, if the user has Safari and selects no. I'm using Safari 9.1 in OSX 10.10 (so it's not the Safari 5 issue in Windows).

The input fields are prepopulated with data from the backend, but if we can update the geolocation data from the browser, we do.

When I select yes in Safari, it grabbed and added the correct data. After I selected no, it just ignored everything and did the default action, either submitting the form with default data or following the link without adding any parameters and the alerts don't alert. Since the functions to make the links work are commented out, the link shouldn't even work (and it's happening instantly, so the setTimeout function isn't the issue).

I had just `e.preventDefault`, and it works everywhere else. StackOverflow offered suggestions of `stopPropagation` and `return false`, neither of which have helped.

Here's the HTML (plus some JSP)

```
<div id="search">
    <form action="/redir/xtsearch" method="get">
        <input id="q" type="text" autocomplete="off" name="search_term" value="" placeholder="Search">
        <button id="search-submit" class="get-geo-location-lat-lng" type="submit">GO</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="esn" value="<c:out value='${plugin_subscriber.result.esn}' />">
        <input type="hidden" name="m" value="<c:out value='${plugin_subscriber.result.mdn}' />">
        <input type="hidden" name="zip" value="<c:out value='${plugin_subscriberlocation.result.postalCode}' />">
        <input type="hidden" name="lat" value="<c:out value='${plugin_subscriberlocation.result.lat}' />">
        <input type="hidden" name="lng" value="<c:out value='${plugin_subscriberlocation.result.long}' />">
    </form>
</div>
<nav id="local">
    <ul>
        <li><c:choose><c:when test="${pageContext.request.contextPath == '/index'}"><a href="/retailers">Retailers</a></c:when> <c:otherwise> <a href="/appsandgames">Free Games</a> </c:otherwise></c:choose></li>
         <li><a href="/traffic">Maps</a></li>
        <li><a href="local" class="get-geo-location-lat-lng">Local search</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And the JavaScript

```
$('.get-geo-location-lat-lng').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var this_link = $(this), 
        this_href = $(this).attr('href'),
        geoOptions = {
            enableHighAccuracy: false,
            timeout: 5000, // Wait 5 seconds
            maximumAge: 300000 //  Valid for 5 minutes
        },
        ESN = $('[name="esn"]').val(),
        MDN = $('[name="m"]').val();
    function gotCoords(lat,lng) {
        if (this_link.is("button")) {
            $('[name="lat"]').val(lat);
            $('[name="lng"]').val(lng);
            $('#search form').submit();
        } else {
            //get variables from velocity injected code on the page
            window.location = this_href + '?brand=TF2&esn=' + ESN + '&m=' + MDN + '&lat=' + lat + '&lng=' + lng;
        }
    }
    function noBrowserGeoLoc(){
        if (this_link.is("button")) {
            $('#search form').submit();
        } else {
            var lat = $('[name="lat"]').val(),lng = $('[name="lng"]').val();
            window.location = this_href + '?brand=TF2&esn=' + ESN + '&m=' + MDN + '&lat=' + lat + '&lng=' + lng;
        }
    }
    try {
        if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, geoOptions);
            function success(pos) {
                var lat = pos.coords.latitude, lng = pos.coords.longitude;
                alert('Success');
                //gotCoords(lat,lng);
            }
            function error()  {
                alert('Failure');
                //noBrowserGeoLoc();
            }
        }
        setTimeout(noBrowserGeoLoc,6000); //Workaround for FireFox bug
    } catch(err) {
        alert('different fail');
        //noBrowserGeoLoc();
    }
    return false;
});
```